# Можно ли задать свой атрибут тэгу "А" в html коде?

Tags: html

При проверке на валидность W3c ругается на то, что у тега "А" неизвестный атрибут в моем случае это "tid" по нему скрипт ловит нажатие на кнопку и добавляет товар в корзину.

```
<a class="add-cart-style-grid" tid="'.$row["products_id"].'" >купить</a>
```

Можно ли сделать этот атрибут валидным или как поступить?

Comment: Не могу понять, как вставить код (<a class="add-cart-style-grid" tid="'.$row["products_id"].'" >купить</a>)

Comment: в редакторе кнопка `{}`

Comment: Валидация при отсутствии синтаксических ошибок - это рекомендация. Семантику она не учитывает.

Comment: т.е можно не обращать внимание на эту рекомендацию?

Comment: Надо использовать `data-атрибуты`. `<a data-tid="bla-bla-bla" ...` В javascript есть специальные функции для data. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пока писал пример в комментах уже ответили, используйте [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) атрибуты

```js
$(function(){
  $("a").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
      alert($(this).data("tid"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<a class="add-cart-style-grid" data-tid="123" >купить</a>
<a class="add-cart-style-grid" data-tid="test" >купить</a>
<a class="add-cart-style-grid" data-tid="magazin" >купить</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо Всем за подробные ответы!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :) Очень помогли!